# The function $\left(a^x+b^x\right)^{{1}/{x}}$ is decreasing.

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

Let $a,b>0$, consider the function $f:\hspace{0,1cm}(0,+\infty)\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $$f(x)=\left(a^x+b^x\right)^{{1}/{x}}.$$
How can i demonstrate that $f$ is monotone decreasing using derivatives?.

My attempt: I'm trying to demonstrate that $f'(x)$ is negative for all $x$, but it is difficult for me, indeed $$f'(x)=(a^x+b^x)^\frac{1}{x}\left( \frac{(\ln a) a^x+(\ln b) b^x}{x(a^x+b^x)} -\frac{\ln(a^x+b^x)}{x^2}\right).$$ Another way to works it?

Answer (score 2):

Let $b\geq a$.

Thus, we need to prove that:
$$(a^x+b^x)(x\ln a +\ln\left(1+\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^x\right)\geq x\left(a^x\ln a+b^x\ln b\right)$$  or
$$(a^x+b^x)\ln\left(1+\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^x\right)\geq b^xx\ln\frac{b}{a}$$
Now, let $\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^x=t$.

Thus, $t\geq1$ and we need to prove that $$(1+t)\ln(1+t)-t\ln{t}\geq0,$$ which is true because $$((1+t)\ln(1+t)-t\ln{t})'=\ln(1+t)-\ln{t}>0$$ and $2\ln2-1\ln1>0.$